# How to render props values on AutoComplete MUI tags

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI Autocomplete component using tags and I can't show the selected roles values that comes from the component props which is collab.roles.

I have the allRoles that haves all the roles that the user can choose from, and he does it's saved and we come back to the autocomplete, it should render the roles that he selected.

I tried using renderTags but it didnt work

Any help would be appreciated !

```
const RoleCollabRow: React.FC<Iprops> = ({ collab }) => {

console.log(collab.roles);
// [
//  {id:1, label:"A"},
//  {id:2, label:"B"}
//]

console.log(allRoles);
/*
[
   {id:1, label:"A"},
   {id:2, label:"B"},
   {id:3, label:"C"},
   {id:4, label:"D"},
   {id:5, label:"E"},
]
*/
        <Autocomplete
          classes={{ inputRoot: isBigScreen ? classes.autoCBigScreen : classes.autoC }}
          multiple
          disableCloseOnSelect
          disableClearable
          limitTags={3}
          options={allRoles}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label || ""}
          renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
            <li {...props} key={option.id}>
              <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
                <Typography style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}>
                  <Checkbox checked={selected} /> {option.label}
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </li>
          )}
          placeholder={selectedRole.length === 0 ? "Non attribué" : ""}
          autoHighlight
          onChange={handleChangeRole}
          onClose={handleCloseAutoComplete}
          inputValue={searchRole}
          onInputChange={(e, value) => setSearchRole(value)}
          style={{ width: 400 }}
          renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) => {
            return collab.roles.map((option, index) => (
              <Chip {...getTagProps({ index })} label={option.label} />
            ));
          }}
        />
```

Comment: What are you doing inside the handleChangeRole function?

Comment: I add the new selected roles to a state and on the handleCloseAutocomplete i send those selected roles to the backend